# Upper bound for $|3x - 2|$ given $|x+3| < 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, absolute-value

I am given a condition $|x+3| < 2$ to find the upper bound of $|3x - 2|$. I am not quite sure if my process is correct.
\begin{align*}
|x+3|<2 & \Longleftrightarrow -2 < x + 3 < 2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -6 < 3x + 9 < 6\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -17 < 3x - 2 < -5
\end{align*}

Is it safe to assume that the upper bound of $|3x - 2|$ is $-5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the upper bound is actually 17 because when you take the absolute value it makes it positive. Also, the RHS of your inequalities should be -5 instead of 5.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! It should be -5. Also I have a question. When you said "it makes it positive", do you mean that everything would turn positive no matter which side of the equation it is located?

Comment: Think about how you got from $|x+3|<2$ to $-2<|x+3|<2$. As the last step, you're essentially doing the reverse, so you have to take the bigger of the two numbers in absolute value to get the upper bound.

Comment: Oh okay I understand it now. Thank you so much for the help and clarification!

Comment: My pleasure. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity:
\begin{align*}
|3x - 2| = |3(x + 3) - 9 - 2| = |3(x+3) - 11| \leq 3|x+3| + |11| < 3\times 2 + 11 = 17 
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your argument:

$-17 < 3x - 2 < -5 \implies 3x-2<0 \implies |3x-2|=-(3x-2)$

$-17 < 3x - 2 < -5 \implies 17 > -(3x - 2) > 5 \implies 5 < |3x - 2| < 17 $